# how to exclude string that include space by "grep -v"

Tags: bash, command-line, grep

I have a script that runs by using `bash -c` and I want to know how many process are running with that script.

```
$ ps ax | grep my_script_run | grep -v grep | grep -v "bash -c"
11121 ?        S      0:00 bash -c export PATH="/opt/rbenv/bin:$PATH"; ruby my_script_run.rb
11173 ?        Rl    19:38 ruby my_script_run.rb
```

Somehow with the command above doesn't exclude `bash -c` string.

```
$ ps ax | grep my_script_run | grep -v grep | grep -v bash
11173 ?        Rl    19:42 ruby my_script_run.rb
```

This command works fine, but I want to exclude `bash -c`, not `bash` itself.
Why the first command doesn't exclude `bash -c`?
And how can I exclude it properly?

### Edit

I forgot to write I'm using `wc -l` after the `grep`

Comment: You don't need to change anything to exclude strings with spaces in - the command you've written here *should* work, and it does when I try it (although I don't have your ruby script). What version of `grep` are you using, and is it aliased to anything?

Comment: I use `alias grep='grep --color=auto -i'`, that causes changes color of `-c` and therefore it doesn't match with it. Thanks!

Comment: I also have `alias grep='grep --color=auto` -- the "auto" means that color codes are only sent to the terminal, not when redirected to pipe/file.

Comment: I also aliased `ps` with `alias ps='grc ps'`, that was the real reason of the behavior. I only checked if the command works with another user.

Comment: you want to keep 'bash' and exclude 'bash -c' ?

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
ps ax | grep -c [m]y_script_run
```

which should count 2  process.

Or

```
\ps ax  | \grep  '[m]y_script_run' | \grep -v 'bash -c' -c
```

where (edit)

- `-c` will count line
- `[m]y_script_run` is a regexp trick to grep `my_script_run` but not itself. (drawback is that it only work on fixed string, not in `${myvar}`). Thanks to @G-Man this string should be quoted.
- `\ps` and `\grep` unalias grep and ps (just in case)

Comment: I didn't know about the option `grep -c`, thanks. But your code excludes `bash`, not the `bash -c`.

Comment: If you're going to use a string like `[m]y_script_run` as a command-line argument, you should quote it (or escape the `[`).  Otherwise, if you use it in the directory where the `my_script_run` file is, it will be subjected to pathname "expansion" by the shell, and, as a result, it will collapse to just `my_script_run`.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid **grep** treat `-c` as option there are few ways where some of it are

1. `grep -v -- 'bash -c'`
2. `grep -v 'bash \-c'`
3. …